# Pharo PipeableOSProcess leaving zombies

Tags: pharo

I'm trying to get the type that results after executing a code snippet. In order to avoid the side effects of that snippet I'm trying to spawn a new Pharo instance to evaluate the code, so I do this

```
codeWrapper := 'bash pharo Pharo.image eval '' (', code , ') class'' '.
^ (PipeableOSProcess command: codeWrapper) output trim.
```

I am running the source Pharo headless on Linux. After going through a few iterations of this the Pharo process leaves a child zombie and does not proceed. I see the child zombie in htop (clearly marked with the Z status).

Any Idea why this is happening and how can it be avoided?

Comment: That's very weird. If the parent has not been suspended, the `SIGCHLD` signal should be consumed be the VM immediately. I know that this can happen if the parent is suspended and the child can be reaped by briefly resuming the parent, but I'm pretty sure that you're not suspending the parent (or are you?). To me it looks more like the parent has stopped working correctly and *can't* consume the `SIGCHLD` signal.